# MailKit Imap Get Mail Size

Tags: c#, mailkit

I use mailkit library to read imap mails. I want to get mail with it's size. In Pop3 I can read mail size with;

```
clientPop.GetMessageSize("messageId");
```

In Imap,how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to get message metadata in IMAP is to use the `Fetch()` method on the folder. If you want to get the size of each message, you could do:

```
foreach (var summary in inbox.Fetch (0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Size)) {
    Console.WriteLine ("The size of message {0} is {1}", summary.Index, summary.Size.Value);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the mail size via the MimeMessage? I'm getting the mails via `inbox.GetMessage(uid)`

Comment: You could write it to a `MimeKit.IO.MeasuringStream` and see what the `Length` is after you do.